# Rank Values per Day in Excel

Tags: excel, rank

I have hourly (temperature) data for each day of the year, for multiple years (8,760 records per year).  I need to rank the temperatures high to low for each day.

I've used the "rank" function in excel, but I need something that will rank only the 24 hours within each day.

Ideally, I'd like to end up with an output that consists only of the n highest values for each day, but just ranking them is fine too since I can filter and delete the records I don't need.

I need the temperatures in one column, and another column that indicates its rank within the day 1-24.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ***Rank if*** formula from [ExcelJet](https://exceljet.net/formula/rank-if-formula)

```
=COUNTIFS(criteria_range,criteria,values,">"&value)+1
```

**Given:**

`criteria_range` = your date column

`criteria` = date cell in current row

`values` = your temperature column

`value` = temperature cell in current row